# What is the term for structure member initialization inside the definition?

Tags: c++

Consider the following example program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct FooBar {
    bool test{true}; // What is this syntax called?
};

int main() {
    FooBar bar;
    printf("%d\n", bar.test);
}
```

What is the name of the syntax for the initialization on the line with the comment?

Comment: [Uniform Initialization](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/133688/is-c11-uniform-initialization-a-replacement-for-the-old-style-syntax)....

Comment: For searching, in-class member initializer / initialization will probably serve you well. That's not a "holy standard" term though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not immediately clear what specifically your question is supposed to be about: the syntax or the feature.

If I correctly understand the scope of your question, the standard meticulously calls this feature "*brace-or-equal-initializers* of non-static data members". Yes, the whole thing.

So, the syntax is of *brace-or-equal-initializer*. And it happens to be used with a non-static data member in your example.

Comment: I was looking for the term so I could Google for the semantics of such initialization. Simply searching for "member initialization in struct definition" was not sufficient.

Answer (score 2):

It's called a *brace-or-equal-initializer* for a non-static data member. Now, it is known as a default member initializer (thanks [P0134](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0134r0.html)).

Comment: Grammatically, `brace-or-equal-initializer` can be applied to things other than NSDMs. So technically, it didn't have a name before.

Answer (score 1):

Grammatically, the initializer is a *brace-or-equal-initializer*, but that is cumbersome to say, and this construction now has a proper technical term, too: *default member initializer* (cf. [class.mem]/8). This term was introduced after C++14 and is currently in the working draft.